# Is the following problem NP-Complete?

Tags: satisfiability, 3-sat, constraint-satisfaction

3SAT with the additional condition that exactly 1 or 3 literals must evaluate to 1.

Answer (score 4):

No. This problem is equivalent to XOR-3SAT, in which we interpret each clause as $x \oplus y \oplus z$, where $\oplus$ is the XOR operator, and ask whether it's possible to find values for all variables so that each clause is true. [XOR-SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#XOR-satisfiability) can be solved in polynomial time using Gaussian elimination, with all arithmetic done modulo 2 (i.e., in the finite field $GF(2)$).

Answer (score 2):

By Schafer's Dichotomy Theorem, if a clause is expressible as a system of linear equations over Zmod2, it is in P. Thus it would not be NP-Complete.

Comment: Using the subjunctive ("if ..." and then "it would not be") gives me the impression that you're talking about a hypothetical situation contrary to reality. How about "These clauses are expressible as a system of linear equations over Z mod 2, so by SDT, the problem is not NP-Complete."